# How to Keep alive dialogflow firebase function to avoid new connection time wastage on each invocation

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using google actions node js library for dialogflow fulfillment. If my google for actions app remains inactive for sometime, dialogflow firebase function really takes very long 16-20 seconds to respond.

However for subsequent invocations it takes 1-3 seconds. So, I want to keep dialogflow firebase function alive so as to avoid time wastage in creating new connection on each function invocation.

I got following article [https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/networking], but it is not useful for me as I don't know how to implement with actions on google library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google. It looks like basic thing, google should have provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as Firebase's cold start issue, which you can learn about [on Medium](https://medium.com/@siriwatknp/cold-start-workaround-in-firebase-cloud-functions-8e9db1426bd3).

One solution is moving from Firebase Functions to GCP's [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/). App Engine is always running, so you won't encounter the 16 - 20 seconds spin-up delay.

Comment: Thanks Max. However I found the answer to this problem from the same link I posted above (i.e. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/networking). Just adding two lines of code solved the problem. Now response is quite prompt. I added following lines: 
1.  const agent = new http.Agent({keepAlive: true});
2. agent: agent,